# Embed MP4 in HTML using flash-player

Tags: html, flash, mp4

Can I embed MP4-files streaming using a flash-player? I find several places it is mentioned, but some places also mention that flash-10 might be a requirement, it might now work well for streaming etc...

Are there any limitations I should be aware of - and which embeddable flash-player works well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can. Flash 9.0.115 is required.

[Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) is my favourite. Free and opensource.

Comment: Not true: "The Free version is licensed under a GPL based License. Use it freely in every possible situation including commercial projects."

Comment: No longer free and no longer opensource. They are only interested in supporting HTML5, which is a catch22 because with HTML5 who needs FlowPlayer.

Answer (score 3):

MP4 files need to be encoded or fixed using a utility or server code to be fast start - the header information at the beginning of the file rather than the end.

Answer (score 2):

The program to move the metadata to the front of the file is here:
http://rndware.info/products/metadata-mover.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Video.Js  .. http://videojs.com/ .. The best Html5 Video player.

Comment: The request was for a Flash player and not HTML5. A player is not needed for HTML5.

Comment: @Williamk Thanks for your comment. Why don't you burn your remaining free time by commenting on all other answers (which suggest an HTML5 player) too? It will be just as helpful as your comment above. Thanks!

Comment: @ Eswar I came across this question while looking for a suitable FLASH player, and this question was about a FLASH player, so following the recommendation of VideoJS was a complete waste of time because it is only a HTML5 player... others should know (unless your answer is removed) so they don't waste their time. If you are the author of VideoJS, well done. Otherwise please don't spam where it is NOT a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of players:

- [MediaElement](http://mediaelementjs.com/): Supports HTML5 and Flash (automatically, if browser needs it).  Free and works well for basic configurations.  Warning: This project has [A LOT](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues) of open issues so if your configuration is having problems you're out of luck
- [f4player](https://github.com/gokercebeci/f4player): It one of the smallest available at only 10kb and free under the GPL license.  It supports flv, f4v, mp4, stream and live stream.  It has not been updated in a while though.
- [Video.js](http://videojs.com/): Don't let the super lame project name fool you. This project is awesome and the best supported of the options.  We've been using it on production software for years with no issues.  This is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this also helpfull with video on website:
Jwplayer

[www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)

Answer (score 0):

I know also a great video player who supported MP4, Flv and MP4 format: it's KAWA Player ->
http://monmoulin.fr/kawa_player_video_flash.html

Of course, it's totally free!

Comment: Not recommended, website is in French only.

Answer (score 0):

here's an open source player

http://hdflvplayer.net/

for supporting MP4 videos and more amazing features!

Comment: It is not free and it cannot play larger mp4 in some browsers. In fact I found that it only worked in Chrome with small files.

Answer (score 0):

FlashFox works well and is very small. See https://code.google.com/p/flashfox/

Download from http://flashfox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ and find usage information on http://v4e.thewikies.com/. You need to provide a full URL for the video, even if it's local.